# How to prevent rollback in trigger before insert and before before update when adderror is thrown

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I'm throwing error before insert when there is duplicate email and performing some action, but when error is thrown all the operation i performed is rolled back. how to prevent rollback.

Comment: addError means that there is an error on record, and it can not be processed. I suggest you to use custom exception throwing, which can be catched

Answer (score 1):

The rollback depends on how the DML was initiated.

1. Insert, update, delete, etc is an all or none and rollback will occur
2. Using database methods you can specify the behavior using the allOrNone option

   Database.insert(records, false);

Will allow records without error to be inserted and those with an error will not.

You can inspect the results using the SaveResult object.

Answer (score 0):

for inserting bulk record use

```
database.Insert
```

It will not rollback all the records it will only add error to specific record.

Answer (score -1):

Salesforce doesn't provide `commit` statement so you could save the data prior to that point and then throw the error.

When you throw any custom error or add an error to a record in Trigger, Salesforce will rollback the transaction. You you cannot change that behavior.

Comment: You can't save and then throw an error. It's not possible. And SF provides a means to alter the all or none behavior